# jQuery: How to write if hasClass statement in a concise way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following if / else if / else statment:

```
if ($('#follow_link_<%=@artist.id%>').hasClass('btn-lg')) {
  $('#follow_link_<%=@artist.id%>').replaceWith("<%=j link_to_follow(@artist,'lg')%>");
} else if ($('#follow_link_<%=@artist.id%>').hasClass('btn-sm')) {
  $('#follow_link_<%=@artist.id%>').replaceWith("<%=j link_to_follow(@artist,'sm')%>");
} else {
  $('#follow_link_<%=@artist.id%>').replaceWith("<%=j link_to_follow(@artist)%>");
}
```

Is there a more concise way to write it?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the overhead of recreating the same jQuery object multiple times by just creating it once and then referencing the object multiple times..

```
var lnkObj = $('#follow_link_<%=@artist.id%>';
if (lnkObj.hasClass('btn-lg')) {
  lnkObj.replaceWith("<%=j link_to_follow(@artist,'lg')%>");
} else if (lnkObj.hasClass('btn-sm')) {
  lnkObj.replaceWith("<%=j link_to_follow(@artist,'sm')%>");
} else {
  lnkObj.replaceWith("<%=j link_to_follow(@artist)%>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
var checkFor = $('#follow_link_<%=@artist.id%>');
if(checkFor.hasClass('btn-lg')){
  newVal = ",'lg'";
} else if(checkFor.hasClass('btn-sm')){
  newVal = ",'sm'";
}
checkFor.replaceWith("<%=j link_to_follow(@artist" + newVal + ")%>");
```